# Do Azure logic apps wait for completion before firing again?

Tags: azure, scheduled-task

We have an Azure logic app that fires every 60 seconds.  It fetches a URL.  Typically this would only take < 1s, but sometimes if there's a lot of work to do on the other end it can be higher.

Will the Azure logic app service wait to fire again if the previous request is still pending or will it just fire again regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not wait for the previous job to complete, it will fire again.

If you want it to not run if a previous job is not running you would need to add something to your logic app to check for that first.

Comment: Great thanks, I can lock the task in my code so that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a functionality that can make the next run wait so on the first activity of your logic app, click on the 3 dots on the right top corner and set the concurrency control limit as on, and set the Degree of parallelism to 1, then it will wait until the new job is triggered
[This image shows how to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uof6.png)
[This image shows how the runs wait until the previous runs complete(success/Failure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMyIK.png)